# How do you call NetBeans installed by a .sh file from the Command Line?

Tags: command-line, 12.10, netbeans

I installed NetBeans 7.2.1 from http://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=linux&lang=en&option=all via the .sh file but I deleted the launcher from the main menu (alacarte) because I wanted to move it to another section of the menu and now I can't run it so I would appreciate it if someone could tell me which command I could run from the terminal to run it. I'm running 12.10.

I've already attempted asking the question on NetBeans forums but I can't log in so I thought I would ask it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question by looking at the command to launch the desktop icon, which was the code given below. 

Copy and paste the following into terminal: (`ctrl+alt+T`)

```
/bin/sh "/home/username/netbeans-7.2.1/bin/netbeans"
```

Answer (score 1):

Going to `/usr/local/netbeans-7.2.1/bin/`, if you did not installed it with root privileges the path is different: `/home/YOURUSER/netbeans-7.2.1/bin/`. Into the `/bin` directory you will find the netbeans executable.

Comment: Oh, sorry, at the moment I was writting the answer you already found the solution, I just didn't see, but nice you find the answer yourself ^.^

Comment: Good attempt anyway I would never have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Save the following into a file (file name below), change `user` to your user:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=NetBeans IDE 7.2.1
Comment=The Smarter Way to Code
Exec=/bin/sh "/home/user/netbeans-7.2.1/bin/netbeans"
Icon=/home/user/netbeans-7.2.1/nb/netbeans.png
Categories=Application;Development;Java;IDE
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=0
```

Next save the files as `/home/user/Desktop/netbeans-7.2.1.desktop`

You should be able to move the file to the start bar or just double click it on the desktop.